# Proving limit exist except for specific points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I stumbled upon this question that my prof asked during class

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x - 2 \cdot n, & 2 \cdot n \le x < 2 \cdot n + 1 \\ 2 \cdot n - x, & 2 \cdot n - 1 \le x < 2 \cdot n,\end{cases}$$

for every n $\in \mathbb Z$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exist for all $c$ $\in \mathbb R$, except for even integer $c$

Now, I know that I need to prove that right-side limit and left-side limit are equals except for the even integer $c$. But I'm not sure how should I divide the cases I got here, for instance I've been thinking to divide by $c = 2a+1$ for odd and $c = 2a$ with $a \in \mathbb N$, but then I realized from the definition $c$ $\in \mathbb R$, so some cases might not included

any insight would really help, thanks beforehand.

Comment: I may be mistaking something or the question is wrong as for $n=0$, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$.

Comment: @PNDas I tried to ask about the point $c = 0$ to my prof, but he said that I need to point out the question if it's wrong on my answer, so no additional info given

Comment: since you need to equate the left-side limit and the right-side limit, if you prove that they can only be equal at certain points and find that those points are not the points were the two pieces of the function meet, you've proven the function doesn't have a limit at the "junctions" (sorry, english is not my first language and I'm not sure I'm getting all the terms right, but I hope this is comprehensible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is continuous everywhere.

First observe that if $x\in(\text{odd, even}) \text{or}x \in(\text{even, odd})$ then by definition graph of the function is a straight line. so it is continuous and limit exists.

Now suppose $c=\text{even}=2k$ for some k.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x-2k,x\in[2k,2k+1)\\2k-x,x\in[2k-1,2k)\end{cases}\implies f(2k)=0$$
The RHL is $f(2k^+)=\lim_{x\to 2k^+}x-2k=0$,similarly LHL is also zero. So the limit exists and the function is continuous at $x=\text{even numbers}$.

Similarly you can check for odd case.

Now suppose $c=\text{odd}=2k+1$ for some k.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2k+2-x,x\in[2k+1,2k+2)\\x-2k,x\in[2k,2k+1)\end{cases}\implies f(2k+1)=1$$
The RHL is $f(2k+1^+)=\lim_{x\to 2k+1^+}2k+2-x=1$,similarly LHL is also one. So the limit exists and the function is continuous at $x=\text{odd numbers}$.

Comment: thanks for the reply! is it sufficient by dividing $c$ to odd and even cases? what about $c \in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: I wrote that in the first paragraph if a point lies inbetween two consecutive integers, the graph is a straight line so it is continuous hebce limit exists.